# Allow traffic from any instance in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a security group that allows all inbound traffic originating from within my VPC. I thought I could simply specify my CIDR block, but that doesn't seem to work and requests fail unless I create a rule which allows inbound traffic from anywhere.

What's the right way to allow inbound traffic from any EC2 instance within the same VPC?

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask that here? Isn't SU or SF a better place?

Comment: @rene Yeah, thats probably true. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work just fine.

For example, if your VPC is setup with a CIDR range of `10.0.0.0/16`, you can create a Security Group with an Inbound rule and a source of `10.0.0.0/16`.

That will allow inbound access from any Elastic Network Interface (eg instance, load balancer, RDS instance) within the VPC.

Make sure that you access the target instance via its Internal IP Address. Using its Public IP Address will fail the Security Group check since it is coming from outside the allowed CIDR range.

Comment: This seems right and it's what I thought as well, but it doesn't seem to be working. I cannot SSH into the other instance despite adding a rule with CIDR range for ssh port 22. If I add the IP of the machine I'm SSH'ing from then it does work.